# Visual Studio (2010 & 11) keep referencing the .net 4 assemblies, even after .net 4.5 is installed

Tags: .net, visual-studio

.Net 4.5 installs to the directory

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319

Visual Studio 2010 installs .Net 4.0 to the directory

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0

Even if .Net 4.5 is installed prior to VS 2010.  Now, no matter what I do, both VS 2010 and VS 11 keep referencing the assemblies in

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0

Even if I remove the assembly from the project, and add the assembly by browsing to the 4.5 directory

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319

How do I get Visual Studio to reference the .Net assemblies located here

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319 ??

Thanks

Comment: Did you change the project to be for .NET 4.5 instead of 4.0?

Answer (score 5):

You have to update the target framework version and choose .Net 4.5 in project properties:

[image]

Comment: I didn't get that option in VS2010 - I'll have to check VS 11

Comment: @Drew You have to use VS 11 to target .Net 4.5.

Comment: VS 11 is working - I wish VS2010 was.  According to the docs, .Net 4.5 will do an inplace update of .Net 4, and VS 2010 can use the .Net 4.5 assemblies - I had this working with the Developers Preview, though it was a little tricky to setup.