# .Net 4.5 not installing correctly?

Tags: entity-framework, .net-4.5, entity-framework-5

I just downloaded and installed .net 4.5 and it went through the installer successfully, I got all the successful install messages, restarted my machine, and nothing.

My C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework was supposed to have a 4.5 folder in it now, and it doesn't.  Also, I can't change any of my projects to 4.5 in visual studio, which I was supposedly able to do also.  I followed Scott Hanselman's blog [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NETVersioningAndMultiTargetingNET45IsAnInplaceUpgradeToNET40.aspx) and I'm not getting the same result.

Also, one of my interns did the same thing today and got the exact same result on his own machine.

Ultimately all I want to do is run EF 5 so I can get fricken enums! And I thought I had to have 4.5 to do that.

Thanks!

Comment: You said you followed the blog but just making sure you targeted .NET Framework 4.5 explicitly like shown here http://stackoverflow.com/a/9637126/1207991? Also you might want to install Visual Studio 2012 RC if you haven't already that automatically installs .NET 4.5. When I uninstalled .NET 4.5 Visual Studio 2012 crashed on me.

Comment: Don't pay too much attention to what Hanselman says, he's a hack and Strahl got it right.  Unstated but key is that you need VS2012 installed to get the selection.  On VS2010 you'll actually get 4.5 at runtime but can't take advantage of 4.5 specific additions since the reference assemblies are still 4.0.  Might work for EF btw.  Don't install betas on machines you need to get your job done.

Comment: @Gloopy, did you ever figure out what it was about 2012 that crashed your machine?

Comment: Also, both of you, this is very helpful... If you'll post your comments as answers I'll upvote both and mark Hans as the answer... Thanks for the insight!

Comment: Uninstalling .NET Framework 4.5 crashed VS 2012 when trying to open it. The reason I uninstalled 4.5 in the first place was due to this (apparently obscure?) bug http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/737108/accessviolationexception-bug-in-net-4-5-beta. VS 2012 worked fine after re-installing .NET 4.5.